# how to convert varchar column into integer when it contains numeric and non numeric values

Tags: mysql, sql

I've table abc in MySQL database consist of a column score_value with varchar data type.It contains numbers and strings.

I wanted to get rid of non_numeric entries. which is relatively easy by using this code:

```
SELECT *  FROM abc WHERE score_value*0 != score_value;
```

It's returning all numeric values.

Now, I want to convert the data type from varchar to int or numeric.

I read many blogs but failed to generate a valid query. Please suggest a straightforward solution. Thanks in advance.

Regards

```
create table xyz AS 
select * FROM abc 
WHERE score_value*0 != score_value 
ORDER BY CAST(`score_value` AS SIGNED);
```

Comment: I've removed the SQL Server tag because this is a MySQL question.  It's best to tag only the RDBMS you are using, as SQL-Server solutions often won't work on MySQL.

Comment: Here's a link to the MySQL docs:  [ALTER TABLE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html).